# scientific notation and filtering

Tags: r

I've got data frame like below (some values in pvalue columns are very small and written in scientific notation).

```
name    pvalue
cos4    5,0496654244484e-18
cos5    4,587533267266e-18
cos6    2,4394418099441e-09
cos7    0,00838023101207848
cos8    <NA>
cos9    <NA>
cos10   0,000168759927743379
cos11   0,000170964058280811
cos12   2,00211463723831e-08
```

I need to filter out the rows, which pvalue is lower than 0.05. Code is below

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(pvalue < 0.05) %>% nrow()
```

The results should be 7, but R says that is 3 (number in scientific notation are treated as 2 or 3, not 2e-08). How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `df$pvalue` a character? (R uses decimal **point** for numbers) Why the result should be 7? 5e-18 is less than 0.05 (test it: `5e-18 < 0.05` gives `TRUE`)

Comment: Not related, but you just can do this `sum(df$pvalue < 0.05)`

Comment: @jogo Yes, that was the problem
> is.character(df$pvalue)
[1] TRUE

Thanks a lot.